# Canadian citizen living in Canada wants to gift a US property to a Canadian living in the US. What do I all need to know?

Tags: united-states, canada, real-estate, property-taxes

My uncle wants to gift a piece of property in the USA that apparently is worth about $8,000 to my sister and I.  We are both Canadian citizens living in the US as permanent residents.  Just curious how this would work?  Are there a lot of fees/taxes etc?  We do simple taxes and do not own any other properties etc.  Anyone know the rules etc, or anything we would need to know. Thanks so much!

Comment: When you say "property", what do you mean exactly - real estate? Maybe a car that is sitting on a parking lot in the US? This will impact where the transaction might be taxable.

Comment: Yes sorry it is a piece of land.

Comment: Anyone have any knowledge?  I need to give him an answer but I have no clue about this stuff? :)

Comment: Has anyone been in this situation before?  Please help!!!!  Where would I even go to ask this information?

Comment: What state is the property located in? This could impact local taxes & fees on transfer.  In general, Canada doesn't tax gifts received or given; the US taxes the giver of gifts, but there are annual and lifetime exemptions which should allow this to be tax free. I am not familiar enoug to get sources for a soiid answer. Your big issue will be local transfer elements. Googleour state's finance departments for info.